# find common elements from two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if any of the rows from peaks is present in output of itertools combination

```
utl = np.array([
 [  3. ,  134.5  , 17. ,  135.1  , 42.,   136.12 ,  0.04],
 [ 12. ,  134.35 , 17. ,  135.1  , 42.,   138.85 ,  0.15],
 [ 17. ,  135.1  , 21. ,  135.   , 36.,   134.68 , -0.02],
 [ 21. ,  135.   , 26. ,  134.75 , 41.,   134.   , -0.05],
 
 ])

Peaks = np.array([

[  3. ,        134.5  ],
[ 12. ,        134.35 ],
[ 17. ,        135.1  ],
[ 21. ,        135    ],
[ 26. ,        134.75 ],
[ 34. ,        135.05 ]

])

for combination in itertools.combinations(utl,2): 
    print(combination[0],combination[1])
```

output is

```
[  3.   134.5   |17.   135.1|   42.   136.12   0.04] 
[ 12.   134.35  |17.   135.1|   42.   138.85   0.15]
#17 135.1 is present in peaks  and in both rows so return 17 135.1


[  3.   134.5  |17.   135.1|   42.   136.12   0.04] 
[|17.   135.1|  21.   135.    36.   134.68  -0.02]
#17 135.1 is present in peaks  and in both the rows so return 17 135.1

[  3.   134.5   17.   135.1   42.   136.12   0.04] 
[ 21.   135.    26.   134.75  41.   134.    -0.05]
#return None as nothing is common 


[ 17.   135.1   |21.   135.|    36.   134.68  -0.02] 
[ |21.   135.|    26.   134.75  41.   134.    -0.05]
#return 21 135 as it is present in peaks and is common in both the rows
```

that is common values from both the rows  must be present in Peaks

Comment: You should better explain the logic of what you try to achieve, only in respect to utl and Peaks.

Comment: want to check if output of itertools combinations has something in common and if yes then is it available in peaks

Comment: You end up with "*answers without using itertools are also accepted*", so itertools is part of your solution, not part of the logic ;) Can you rephrase the logic independently of `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: using itertools just to combine rows i.e row 0 of utl with row 1 of utl ,  row 0 of utl with row 2 of utl  and so on . so if the same can be done by using other  methods like pure numpy then it is also accepted

Comment: sorry, giving up on this question, the requirements are too unclear

Comment: forget about itertools . what i want is if the output of itertools has something in common and if there is then is it available in the array peaks

Answer (score 0):

```
for combination in itertools.combinations(utl,2):
print(combination[0],combination[1])
common = np.intersect1d(combination[0], combination[1]) # get common values 
for p in Peaks:
    common_peak = np.intersect1d(common, p)
    if len(common_peak)>0:
        print(common_peak)
print("------------------------------------------------")
```

I think that there are more efficient ways to do this, but it does what you ask.

EDIT

A faster solution is to cycle on `Peaks` and to find matches in single elements of `utl`:

```
for p in Peaks:
    print(p) #peak 'p'
    matches = ((utl==p[0])+(utl==p[1])).sum(axis=1)>=2
    print(utl[matches]) #utl elements matching with the peak 'p'
    print("----------------------------------------------")
```

if the `utl[matches]` are more than 2 lines you can use `itertools` to have single pairs:

```
itertools.combinations(utl[matches],2)
```

Comment: yes it does what i want but I want efficient way to do it

Comment: For this you should clearly explain the goal ;)

Comment: @user18083011 I think that if you want the efficent way you should work backwards. cycling on `Peaks`. I'll show u in the edit